# cv::imwrite doesn't save CV_32FC4 cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use `CV_32FC4` in `cv::Mat` so it stores a `RGBA32` image. but when i use `cv::imwrite` to save it as a `png` file, the result file is always a **empty** image.

for example, i create a image like this:

```
   cv::Mat f4(50, 50, CV_32FC4);

   for (int i = 0; i < 50 * 50; ++i)
   {
      *(FLOAT4*)(f4.data + i * sizeof(FLOAT4)) = FLOAT4(i % 50 / 50.0f, i / 2500.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
   }  
   cv::imwrite("32FC4.png", f4); //"32FC4.png" will be an empty image file, 
                                 //size is 249 B, not white or black,
                                 //a transparent image.
```

Comment: according to the doc (it really helps): http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite imwrite `Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function.`

Comment: @Micka actually I did save a CV_32FC3 to file successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only save uchar/ushort types as png, not float or double.

use:

```
Mat bgra8;
f4.convertTo(bgra8, CV_8UC4, some_scale_factor);
imwrite("my.png", bgra8);
```

if you need to keep the precision, and your Mat is fairly small, use FileStorage, and write to a *text* file:

```
FileStorage fs("my.yml",FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "f4" << f4;
fs.release();
```

later, read it back:

```
Mat f4;
FileStorage fs("my.yml",FileStorage::READ);
fs["f4"] >> f4;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful to some people who come to this thread, with the same problem.

*If* you are trying to save a floating point Mat (e.g. CV_32FC4 or CV16FC4), for the purpose of inspecting the values stored in the image,
then you can save it as a .tiff file

```
cv::imwrite("<fliename_32FC4>.tiff", <Mat_name>)
```

and open it with your favorite image editor (e.g. Gimp).
This is easier to view and interpret than a text file for Mat objects with >1000 pixels.

In Gimp, select "*windows->dockable dialogs->pointer*" to see the channel values for the selected pixel. You may need to tell Gimp how to interpret the fourth channel, e.g. as "non-pre-multiplied alpha channel". If the value in the 4th channel is far from 1.0, then adjust the color_curve for the alpha channel, to make the image visible.